# Playing video with audio on a Tkinter frame

Tags: python, opencv, vlc

So I'm trying to do something really janky. I'm using opencv and ffpyplayer to try to make an embedded video player on a Tk window.

It does work but i'm having issue syncing the audio and the video, i can get close to a decent result but after a bit it goes out of sync again.

whole code:

```
import time, traceback, os, telepot
from tkinter import *
import cv2, youtube_dl # pip install opencv-python; pip install --upgrade 
youtube_dl
from PIL import Image, ImageTk #
from io import BytesIO # io
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer # pip install ffpyplayer
from pytube import YouTube

_name_ = os.path.basename(os.path.realpath(__file__))
_path_ = os.path.realpath(__file__).replace(_name_, '')

class Screen(Frame):
    '''
        Screen widget: Embedded video player from local or youtube
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg = 'black')
        self.settings = { # Inizialazing dictionary settings
            "width" : 1024,
            "height" : 576
        }
        self.settings.update(kwargs) # Changing the default settings
        # Open the video source |temporary
        self.video_source =  _path_+'asd.mp4'

        # Inizializing video and audio variables
        self.vid = None
        self.aux = None
        # Canvas of the player
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width = self.settings['width'], height = self.settings['height'], bg = "black", highlightthickness = 0)
        self.canvas.pack()

        # NEED TO SYNC AUDIO
        self.delay = 15 # Delay between frames of player

    def update(self):
        '''
            Function: Start the player and keeps drawing the canvas 
        '''
        if not self.vid or not self.aux: # If Audio or Video is missing stop everything
            self.stop()
            return None

        # Get the frames and if video and audio are running
        ret, frame = self.get_frame()
        audio_frame, val = self.aux.get_frame()

        # Drawing frames on canvas
        if self.fb == 1: # Check if it's the first cycle, trying to make the audio start with the video
            self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = Image.fromarray(frame).resize((self.settings['width'], self.settings['height'])))
            self.canvas.create_image(0,0, image = self.photo, anchor = 'nw')
            self.fb = 0
            self.aux.set_pause(False) # Starting the audio
        elif ret and val != 'eof':
            self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = Image.fromarray(frame).resize((self.settings['width'], self.settings['height'])))
            self.canvas.create_image(0,0, image = self.photo, anchor = 'nw')

        self.after(self.delay, self.update) # Update for single frame, need to sync

    def get_frame(self):
        '''
            Function: Draws the frames
        '''
        if self.vid.isOpened():
            ret, frame = self.vid.read()
            if ret:
                # Return a boolean success flag and the current frame converted to BGR
                return (ret, cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            else:
                return (ret, None)

    def youTube(self, ID):
        '''
            Function: Gets the youtube video and starts it 
        '''
        print("(TO REPLACE) : Downloading")
        yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + ID)
        stream = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True).first() # SEE THE POSSIBLE THINGS TO DOWNLOAD
        stream.download(_path_, 'test')
        print("(TO REPLACE) : Finished")
        self.start(_path_+'\\test.mp4')

    def start(self, _source):
        '''
            Function: Starts the player when gets input from keyboard(temporal) or Telegram
        '''
        try: # Stopping player if is already playing for a new video
            self.stop()
        except:
            None

        ff_opts = {'paused' : True} # Audio options
        self.fb = 1 # Setting first cycle

        if _source == 'local': # Checking which source use
            self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video_source)
            self.aux = MediaPlayer(self.video_source, ff_opts=ff_opts)
        else:
            self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(_source)
            self.aux = MediaPlayer(_source, ff_opts=ff_opts)

        if not self.vid.isOpened():
            raise ValueError("Unable to open video source")

        self.update() # Starting the player

    def stop(self):
        '''
            Function: Release and stop Video and Audio
        '''
        try: # Stopping video
            self.vid.release()
            self.vid = None
        except:
            pass
        try: # Stopping audio
            self.aux.toggle_pause()
            self.aux = None
        except:
            pass
        self.canvas.delete('all') # Resetting canvas

    def __del__(self):
        '''
            Function: Release the video source when the object is destroyed
        '''
        if self.vid.isOpened():
            self.vid.release()

class Mirror:
    '''
        Mainframe: Display where to put the widgets
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk() # Creating the window
        self.tk.configure(background = 'black')
        self.tk.update()

        # Setting up the FRAMES for widgets
        self.bottomFrame = Frame(self.tk, background = 'black')
        self.bottomFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill = BOTH, expand = YES)

        # Bindings and fullscreen setting
        self.fullscreen = False
        self.tk.bind("<Return>", self.toggle_fullscreen)
        self.tk.bind("<Escape>", self.end_fullscreen)

        # Screen, BOT
        print("Inizializing Screen...")
        self.screen = Screen(self.bottomFrame)
        self.screen.pack(side = TOP)

        self.tk.bind("<Key>", self.key) # Get inputs from keyboard

    def key(self, event):
        pressed = repr(event.char).replace("'", '')
        if pressed == 's':
            self.screen.stop()
        elif pressed == 'a':
            self.screen.start('local')
        else:
            print('fail')

    def toggle_fullscreen(self, event = None):
        self.fullscreen = True
        self.tk.attributes("-fullscreen", self.fullscreen)

    def end_fullscreen(self, event = None):
        self.fullscreen = False
        self.tk.attributes("-fullscreen", self.fullscreen)

    def on_chat_message(msg):
        content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
        message = str(msg.get('text'))

        if 'https://youtu.be/' in message:
            URL_VIDEO = message.split('https://youtu.be/')[1]
            Mir.screen.youTube(URL_VIDEO)       
        elif 'stop' == message.lower():
            Mir.screen.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Mir = Mirror()
    #bot = telepot.Bot(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)
    #bot.message_loop(on_chat_message)
    Mir.tk.mainloop()
    #while 1:
        #time.sleep(10)
```

in specific the method that renders the frames:

```
# NEED TO SYNC AUDIO
    self.delay = 15 # Delay between frames of player

def update(self):
    '''
        Function: Start the player and keeps drawing the canvas 
    '''
    if not self.vid or not self.aux: # If Audio or Video is missing stop everything
        self.stop()
        return None

    # Get the frames and if video and audio are running
    ret, frame = self.get_frame()
    audio_frame, val = self.aux.get_frame()

    # Drawing frames on canvas
    if self.fb == 1: # Check if it's the first cycle, trying to make the audio start with the video
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = Image.fromarray(frame).resize((self.settings['width'], self.settings['height'])))
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0, image = self.photo, anchor = 'nw')
        self.fb = 0
        self.aux.set_pause(False) # Starting the audio
    elif ret and val != 'eof':
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = Image.fromarray(frame).resize((self.settings['width'], self.settings['height'])))
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0, image = self.photo, anchor = 'nw')

    self.after(self.delay, self.update) # Update for single frame, need to sync
```

I tried other things to make this thing work and looked if i could find a solution but without success, if someone has some ideas or better solution to do this i would appreciate.

Also i tried getting the video from youtube as a stream without needing to download the whole video first to play it, i could get the video to work but i couldn't find a way to get the audio to play, if someone know a way to do it i'd like to know as well.

**edit:**
So the frame rate of the video should be either 24, 30 or 60, I should have a check of the framerate of the video then set a delay accordingly, the way i did it, was that i manually changed the delay depending on the video frame rate trying to make it sync by trial and error. I don't know much of audio honestly so idk about that stuff..

Also to make the whole code run it needs either a token from a telegram bot or a local video file to play.

Comment: Can you only show the most relevant code. So mush code could be overwhelming to the readers. Also may be consider the frame rate of the video and sampling rate(?) of the audio?

Comment: I extracted the relevant method/function. About the frames i just adjusted the delay manually until i found the best timing. For the audio honestly i don't know much at all about audio so i didn't considered anything

Comment: That's not the whole code. What you have provided here is the child class `Screen` that inherits from `Frame`. Where is `Frame` defined? Where is the code that instantiates `Screen` and makes use of it? The code you've dumped here is neither complete nor verifiable, let alone **minimal**. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to include code in your question.

Comment: I now also added the rest of the code, didn't think i needed to add that, should work right away

Comment: @darksky Frame is defined within the tkinter library :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So ok I found a wayyyy better solution to this. I tried using again the vlc module, I had trouble using it before but after I got through it I actually found a way to print the output from vlc to **a frame with a canvas**.

It's actually stupidly simple, I got rid of cv2 and ffpyplayer and used a simple VLC player

Note that in my case Screen is a Frame, so to make this work just use 'Frame'**.winfo_id()** to get the id of the tk frame where to output the video, the audio works as well. Then just use player **.set_hwnd(ID)** to set it to the vlc player.

```
class Screen(Frame):
'''
    Screen widget: Embedded video player from local or youtube
'''
def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg = 'black')
    self.settings = { # Inizialazing dictionary settings
        "width" : 1024,
        "height" : 576
    }
    self.settings.update(kwargs) # Changing the default settings
    # Open the video source |temporary
    self.video_source =  _path_+'asd.mp4'

    # Canvas where to draw video output
    self.canvas = Canvas(self, width = self.settings['width'], height = self.settings['height'], bg = "black", highlightthickness = 0)
    self.canvas.pack()

    # Creating VLC player
    self.instance = vlc.Instance()
    self.player = self.instance.media_player_new()


def GetHandle(self):
    # Getting frame ID
    return self.winfo_id()

def play(self, _source):
    # Function to start player from given source
    Media = self.instance.media_new(_source)
    Media.get_mrl()
    self.player.set_media(Media)

    #self.player.play()
    self.player.set_hwnd(self.GetHandle())
    self.player.play()
```

Comment: Were you able to fix the problem that you posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1421094/multiple-issue-with-vlc-on-debian), because I have the same problem right now.

Comment: @Tomsen Unfortunately i did not find a way to fix it, my guess is that there was some kind of issue trying to do it in a virtual machine, maybe a graphical setting or a bad installation of the virtual machine, in the end i just bought a raspberry and used that

Comment: I use a raspberry and have this problem. But thanks for your answer, I'll just search for an other solution.